# Python: Set Color for Tkinter Button using .grid()

Tags: python, button, tkinter

using the Python 2.7 Tkinter Grid Layouter, i would like to do something like

```
root.button = Button(root, bg = 'green', ....)
root.button.grid(...)
```

in order to get a green button.
Running this, it doesn't bring up any errors, but the button does not take the desired color.
Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
thanks for the code, i copied it and run it, here is what i get: still a white button ..?
[image]

Comment: Are you running this on OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `bg` keyword argument works as expected. Try following:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
button = Button(root, text='buggton', bg='green')
button.grid(row=0, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: @BuroBernd, Ahh, you use osx. See [How do I change the foreground or background colour of a Tkinter button on Max OS X 10.6 with Python 2.6.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529847/how-do-i-change-the-foreground-or-background-colour-of-a-tkinter-button-on-max-o)