# Tkinter button won't configure

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm making a simple game using python and Tkinter. All works well, but I can't seem to change the appearance of the only button in the game (a RESET button on the bottom). It should be flat and blue with white text, to match the rest of the layout. This is the code i'm using now:

```
resetbutton = Button(root, text='RESET', width=15, command=sw.Reset, highlightbackground="blue", relief='flat')
resetbutton.grid(column=5, columnspan=3, row=13, rowspan=1)
```

... but the button still looks like the default one. Anyone got any ideas why this doesn't work?

Comment: If you are running on a Mac, there's nothing you can do. The mac doesn't allow you to change the overall look of buttons.

Comment: @BryanOakley with `ttk` you can set styles and load them with `style=`

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below with **fg** and **bg** (you can also assign fonts [if supported]):

```
Button(root, text='RESET', command=sw.Reset, font='Arial -20 bold', relief='flat', bg='blue', fg='white', width=10, height=2)
```

Comment: I've used bg en fg succesfully for the labels, but for some reason it doesn't do anything with this button.. Also, the relief is still the same even though I use relief='flat' (which is correct syntax I think)..

Comment: Are you on **Mac OS** ?! It had complains of not supporting backgrounds and foregrounds of Buttons in Tkinter. [Hopefully the Link will help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529847/how-do-i-change-the-foreground-or-background-colour-of-a-tkinter-button-on-max-o)

Comment: That's right! Do you know a work around for this issue? I'm coding on a mac, but the game will be used for kids in a school and the school uses only windows so maybe I should just configure and test the button on a windows?

Comment: Yeah ! Its working perfectly on both Windows and Linux. If you are going to run it in windows, then its perfectly fine. Just test your game once on Windows. Haven't found anything yet for Mac.

Comment: Even using `themedtk`, i.e., `ttk`, text color may work but background doesn't work on Mac.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help! I'm gonna switch to a Windows computer now and once the button looks the way I want it, I'll continue the rest of the coding om my own mac :)

Answer (score 0):

The given answer is correct, however, if you hover the mouse upon the button, this later one will change both the blue and white colors to the default ones.

So to keep the same  design when you hover the mouse, you can add these two options for your `resetbutton` button:

- `activebackground="blue"`
- `activeforeground= "white"`