# Need help for buttons declarations

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to python and i just want to create a button with some arguments.
But i can't succeed to have the background color or the relief, but the font works so i really don't understand what's going on.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

window.title("test bouton")
window.geometry("400x400")
button = Button(window, text="click me", fg='blue',  background='grey', relief='sunken')
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

With all the things i saw online i can't find my mistake, can you help me?

Comment: Are you on OSX? OSX has limitations on what it allows for button objects.

Answer (score 0):

We can not change `background`, `relief`, `overrielf`, `activebackground`, and maybe a few other options of a button on a mac system. You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529847/how-to-change-the-foreground-or-background-colour-of-a-tkinter-button-on-mac-os) post.

If you are comfortable in using external libraries then you can try [tkmacosx](https://pypi.org/project/tkmacosx/). `Button` of tkmacosx module will let you eliminate those limitations on mac.

*Example:*

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkmacosx import Button

window = Tk()

window.title("test bouton")
window.geometry("400x400")
button = Button(window, text="click me", fg='blue', bg='grey', borderless=1)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

[image]

To use `relief=sunken` you have to set the `borderwidth` *(or `bd`)* more than 1.

```py
Button(window, text="click me", fg='blue', bg='grey', relief='sunken', bd=3)
```