# Tkinter - change button background color

Tags: python, tkinter

how can I change the background of a button? I tried everything from tutorials I have found but nothing works.

```
class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("A simple GUI")

        self.okayButton = Button(master, text="awdawdaw",bg='blue', activebackground='cyan')
        self.okayButton.pack()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_hi('Hello')

    root = Tk()

    root.geometry("800x480")
    my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: With your code, I see a button with a blue background. What do you see? What OS are you running on? OSX?

Comment: yes mac osx

I see a normal default button with white bg and black coor

Comment: If your platform is MacOS, then you cannot change the background color of a button.  See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529847/how-to-change-the-foreground-or-background-colour-of-a-tkinter-button-on-mac-os).