# Button width and height not working in tkinter tkmacosx

Tags: python, tkinter

when i use tkinter button i get the results i want though i'm using tkinter button from tkmacosx library as it supports background color. The problem is when i replace normal button with tkmacosx button they appear like dots.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkmacosx as tkm
from tkinter.font import Font

root = tk.Tk()
color_list = ('#462066', '#FFB85F', '#FF7A5A', 
              '#00AAA0', '#8ED2C9', '#FCF4D9')

button_font = Font(family="Comic Sans MS", size='30')

for row, bg in enumerate(color_list):
    b1 = tkm.Button(
        root, text='%s'%row, bg=bg, borderless=1,
        width=5, height=3, font=button_font)
    b1.grid(row=row%2, column=row%3)
root.mainloop()
```

images:

tkmacosx buttons appear like this [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MNzl.png) but i want the button to sizes like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfSFI.png).

Thanks

Comment: My guess is that `tkmacosx.Button`'s width is in pixels not characters. Also if you just use `tk.Button` you aren't going to have that problem. Why are you using `tkmacosx`? I don't have a MacOS so I have no glue what that is

Comment: Hi @TheLizzard, In macos we cannot change bg and fg of the button tkmacosx let u do that. you can see that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529847/how-to-change-the-foreground-or-background-colour-of-a-tkinter-button-on-mac-os

Comment: You can also give width and height like `width='5c', height='3c'`. Where *"c" means centimetres*. There are also few other units as well like "I": inches, "m": millimetres and "p": points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to increase number of pixels `width= 200, height = 100`

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkmacosx as tkm
from tkinter.font import Font

root = tk.Tk()
color_list = ('#462066', '#FFB85F', '#FF7A5A',
              '#00AAA0', '#8ED2C9', '#FCF4D9')

button_font = Font(family="Comic Sans MS", size='30')

for row, bg in enumerate(color_list):
    b1 = tkm.Button(root, width=200,  height=100,  text='%s' % row, bg=bg, borderless=1,  font=button_font)
    b1.grid(row=row % 2, column=row % 3)
root.mainloop()
```

here is output
[image: output]

Comment: Ohhh now i understand that it takes sizes in pixels, thanks

Comment: yes, u need to increase your px,   hope helpful for you :)