# Tkinter button not changing colour

Tags: python, tkinter

When the button is clicked, the button should change to orange but its not.

```
from tkinter import *
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('300x300')
    def clicked():
      global clicks
```

Here is the code for color change

```
button.configure(background = 'orange')
        
    button = Button(root, justify=CENTER,text = "Click Me!", command=clicked)
    button.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It still doesnt work @toyotaSupra

Answer (score 0):

I only changed the order of your code.

```
from tkinter import *

def clicked():
    global clicks
    button.configure(background = 'orange')

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
        
button = Button(root, justify=CENTER,text = "Click Me!", command=clicked)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It worked on replit but it doesnt work on vs code. Im using a macbook btw

Comment: I think macbook doesnt support colour changing of buttons :(

Comment: yes I think so. here is another possibility: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529847/how-to-change-the-foreground-or-background-colour-of-a-tkinter-button-on-mac-os