# Can't specify color of tkinter Button

Tags: python, tkinter

I know this is a common SO question, but I must be overlooking something very simple:

```
from tkinter import Tk,Button
root = Tk()  
root.geometry('100x50')  

button = Button(root, bg='blue',text = 'Submit' )
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The button background simply will not change from default gray. On Mac with Monterey 12.5.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the foreground or background colour of a Tkinter Button on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529847/how-to-change-the-foreground-or-background-colour-of-a-tkinter-button-on-mac-os) That was the first Google result.

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to change the actual button color itself. There was a link on that post to info about a separate package for Mac: tkmacosx

Comment: I get the correct button color using tkmacosx, but I find it strange that I had to install a new package.

Comment: The question I linked, is the same as your question and the accepted answer says it's not possible with pure `tkinter`, that is why you had to download another package. For more info on how the other package works, look at its source code.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html), color words work if they are also found in the `rgb.txt` file.

[image]

Out of curiosity, do other common colors work? Like `red, blue, green`? Or nothing works?

Comment: Are you sure that that applies to MacOS as well? If so, doesn't that make [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1530913/11106801) answer invalid?

Comment: @TheLizzard That's interesting... I didn't know `tkinter` leveraged platform specific UI calls. I always assumed they did it themselves considering how awful it usually looks...

Comment: `tkinter` uses the `tcl/tk` library, which is very-very old (nearly as old as C++). Also it's always easier to use OS calls when creating these widgets then creating them from scratch.