# Changing color of tkinter button

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to update the background color of a button when I have clicked on it. But nothing happens. Instead I tried this minimal code snippet, but only the foreground is changed, not the background:

```
from tkinter import *
def demoColorChange():
    button1.configure(bg='red', fg='blue')
parent = Tk()
parent.geometry('500x500')
button1 = Button(parent, text = 'click me!', command= demoColorChange )
button1.pack()
parent.mainloop()
```

This example code can also be found here: https://www.educba.com/tkinter-button-color/

This is on Mac Ventura and Python 3.11.5.
Is there some update I don't know about?

**Update**

Installing tkmacosx and adding the import

```
from tkmacosx import Button
```

made it work!

Comment: You should include your imports in order for this to qualify as a [mre]. I assume you've done `from tkinter import *`, so you should add that here. (Never mind that star imports should be avoided). That said, when I do try to run this (with the appropriate imports), the button turns red with blue text as expected...

Comment: Are you using macosx?.

Comment: Yes this is on Mac, and yes I forgot the imports sorry for that!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the foreground or background colour of a Tkinter Button on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529847/how-to-change-the-foreground-or-background-colour-of-a-tkinter-button-on-mac-os)

Comment: The original code works on my computer.